# JAVA, how to get a List of all filenames inside a directory in jar environment?

Tags: java, file, inputstream

First of all my Project structure:

```
resources
 - config.properties

src
 - Main.java
 - Filter.java
 - module
    - test.txt
```

Now i just want to call a method which gives me all the filenames/files inside the module dir (as example "test.txt") back, this code is working inside my IDE (eclipse):

```
public class Filter {

    public File[] finder(String dirname) {

        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("module");

        try {               
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")); 
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
            // in IDE: prints "test.txt"
            // as a jar: prints "null"

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;        
    }
}
```

Inside my IDE its printing "test.txt", 
but not once i compiled the project to a jar file. After executing it inside the terminal with "java -jar Untitled.jar" it just prints null.

Comment: You can't (more accurately, you shouldn't as any solution is mostly a hack), because it's no longer a directory, it's a Zip file.  A better solution is to  have the contents stored in a file, which can be easily accessed (using `getResourceAsStream`), which can be generated at build time and included in the Jar

Comment: Maybe i missunderstood you, are you suggesting to just use one text file? i can access the test.txt if i replace "module" with "module/test.txt", reading lines also works after that, it would like to have a "system" where the code reads the names of multiple text files inside a dir and then stores their names so later code can access specific files, i want this to be "user friendly" meaning the user only needs to put txt files inside a dir and thats it.

Comment: I'm suggesting you have a single "master" file, which has a list of all the files in your `modules` folder.  This file would be generated at build time and stored in the Jar file (at a specific location), which you would then read, it would then provide you with the list of the other resources which you could then load.  The problem is, a Jar file is just a Zip file, you can not access the contents as if they are "files", because they're not.  The other problem is, you don't have access to the "original" Jar reference, so it's difficult to open it as a Zip file

Comment: thanks yeah, i think ill go that way, have a nice day! :)